# Exception Handling/Mapping for a particular class

Tags: java, exception, jersey, dropwizard

I have resource class which itself's talks with a internal service. This resource acts a rest API for the service. The service layer can throw unexpected exceptions, thus the resource should handle those handled unexpected exceptions and log it. I am using dropwizard framework which in turns use jersey. It goes like this.

```
@PATH(/user)
@GET
public Response getUser(@QueryParam("id") String userId) {
   assertNotNull(userId);
   try {
      User user = service.getUser(userId);
      return Response.ok(user).build();
   }
   catch (MyOwnException moe) { //basically 400's
     return Response.status(400).entity(moe.getMsg()).build();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {   //unexpected exceptions

      logger.debug(e.getMessage);
      return Response.status(500).entity(moe.getMsg()).build();
   }
}
```

The problem here is that i have to do this exact same exception handling for each REST api endpoint. Can i do some kind of exception mapping for this particular resource so that i can put all the handling logic and logging there?
I know i can build a mapper for an particular exception in jersey, but that is for the whole module not a single class.

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665 Documentation on how to use jersey exception mappers, register them etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaig you can't register an `ExceptionMapper` to a resource method. I've tried this by implementing a `DynamicFeature` which was looking for a custom Annotation and then tried to register a custom `ExceptionMapper` with the `FeatureContext`.

The result was disillusioning:
`WARNING: The given contract (interface javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper) of class path.to.CustomExceptionMapper provider cannot be bound to a resource method.`

*Might not work:*
<strike>But...</strike>

For a resource class this is in fact easy. Just register your `ExceptionMapper` for your resource class within your `ResourceConfig`. For me it looks like:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationResourceConfig() {
        // [...]
        register(YourExceptionMapper.class, YourResource.class);
        // [...]
    }
}
```

So if you are okay with having this on resource class level, do it like this.

Otherwise you might need to use Aspects <strike>*(but I don't see any reasons to do so)*</strike>. Example:

#### Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class ResourceAspect {

    Logger logger = [...]

    private static final String RESOURCE = "execution(public !static javax.ws.rs.core.Response path.to.resources..*(..)) && @annotation(path.to.HandleMyOwnException)";

    @Around(RESOURCE)
    public Object translateRuntimeException(ProceedingJoinPoint p) throws Throwable {

        try {
            return p.proceed();
        } catch (MyOwnException moe) {
            return Response.status(400).entity(moe.getMsg()).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {   //unexpected exceptions
            logger.debug(e.getMessage);
            return Response.status(500).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }

}
```

Please notice, the `RESOURCE` config. Here it works for `none static` methods under `path.to.resources` which returning `Response` and are anntotated with the `HandleMyOwnException` annotation.

#### HandleMyOwnException

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface HandleMyOwnException {}
```

#### ResourceMethod

```
@GET
@PATH("/user")
@HandleMyOwnException
public Response getUser(@QueryParam("id") String userId) {
   assertNotNull(userId);
   return Response.ok(service.getUser(userId)).build();
}
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
<!-- deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version> <!-- or newer version -->
</dependency>

<!-- build plugins -->
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <configuration>
            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
<pluginManagement>
```

Have a nice day!

#### EDITED

~ Added more complete pom.xml config
~ Corrected missing path for Annotation in ResourceAspect

Comment: Is the aspectj solution also working when validation is enabled and the parameter does not meet the criteria (e.g. @NotNull)?
And at least for me, the `register(MyExceptionMapper.class, MyResource.class)` hint is not working, I am getting _Contract type not supported_ and _Contract not assignable to component_...

Comment: Can't reproduce Mapper for resource class currently and edited my answer *(might be a version issue, I need to find out later)*. For the aspectj thing: give it a try :)

Comment: I tried with aspectj, but it is as I expected: the method is not executed, because the validation failed and therefore the aspect is never called... :/ So neither with `register(..)`, nor with aspectj, I could not get it working, that an ExceptionMapper is only responsible for a specific resource class...

Comment: I might not got it. You've annotated the methods with `@NotNull` and `@HandleMyOwnException` (or similiar)? Maybe a good idea to formulate your task as a question?!? Please notice: My answer is about adding annotations (for asj) to methodes, not classes.

Comment: Ok. So here is what I have: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c472656ec29efd2a489f3afdec5a3625

Comment: And this is what I would like to have, if your `register(..)` attempt would work: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/198b6a6ef9f2d6042cb5ee64652a0125

Comment: As `@NotNull` is validated before entering the Method, everything is fine. It' just your expectation, which are wrong. `@see` [link](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec) 2.3 Method Validation ... *the preconditions that must be met by the caller **before** the method or constructor may be invoked* - For class level, as I said, it doesnt work and I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just factor out the exception handling into a private method?

```
@PATH(/user)
@GET
public Response getUser(@QueryParam("id") String userId) {
    assertNotNull(userId);
    return handleExceptions(() -> {
        User user = service.getUser(userId);
        return Response.ok(user).build();
    });
}

private Response handleExceptions(Callable<Response> callable) {
    try {
        return callable.call();
    }
    catch (MyOwnException moe) { //basically 400's
        return Response.status(400).entity(moe.getMsg()).build();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {   //unexpected exceptions
        logger.debug(e.getMessage);
        return Response.status(500).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes obviously that can be done, but i was hoping for a more cleaner solution. Isn't there a way to create a Exception mapper  for a particular class?

Comment: I think that is quite clean. If you need to handle errors in a single resource, then the resource itself should do it. Jersey doesn't need to intervene here and I don't think it should, otherwise you end up splitting a single resource logic across multiple classes.

Comment: @user3318096 For class level it is easy, for resource methods afaig not - see my answer

Comment: @andrepnh Splitting up functionality of single resources across multiple classes is our daily business. Cause to provide the resource, you need to accomplish plentiful things. Thats the exact reason why frameworks like Jersey exist. To split exception handling is a decent demand.

Comment: There's a difference between delegating things that doesn't concern you and having someone else do response logic that only you demand. If the resource itself does it, testing, as an example, would be much more straightforward. A simple unit test for the actual resource would be enough.