# Jersey - Register ExceptionMapper for Resource Methods

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

The question [Exception Handling/Mapping for a particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370991) brought me to the question of how to register an `ExceptionMapper` to a particular resource **Method**.

I've tried to use a `DynamicFeature` like this:

#### DynamicFeature

```java
@Provider
public class ExceptionMapperDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext context) {
        if(!resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().isAnnotationPresent(BindExceptionMapper.class))
            return;
        BindExceptionMapper bem = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(BindExceptionMapper.class);
        context.register(bem.mapper());
    }

}
```

#### Annotation

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface BindExceptionMapper {
    Class<? extends ExceptionMapper<?>> mapper() default WebApplicationExceptionMapper.class;
}
```

#### Resource

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@BindExceptionMapper 
public Response test() {
    // do something that throws an exception
}
```

The result was disillusioning:

> WARNING: The given contract (interface javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper) of class ...WebApplicationExceptionMapper provider cannot be bound to a resource method.

Then I was searching for other possibilities without luck and ended up with a AspectJ implementation, which you can see as a [part of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370991/exception-handling-mapping-for-a-particular-class/36374188#36374188) to the linked question above.

So the complete question:

***Is there a way to successfully register an ExceptionMapper to a resource Method?***

And of course,

- if yes then: how?
- if no then: why?

I'm curious about the answers :)

**Please notice:**
This question is not about to register an `ExceptionMapper` to a resource **Class** like...

```java
public class ApplicationResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationResourceConfig() {
        register(WebApplicationExceptionMapper.class, TestResource.class);
    }
}
```

and especially not about to register them at all.

Comment: _"if yes then: how?"_ - N/A (not possible). _"if no then: why?"_ - That's something you need to ask the designers. You seem to have found a solution with AOP. If you want to use AOP, without using another library, HK2 (Jersey's DI framework) has [AOP support](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/extensibility.html#Interception). You can see a [full example with Jersey](https://github.com/mgajdos/jersey-intercepting-resource-methods)

Answer (score 4):

It's not *exactly* what you asked, but it's the only way I've found to do something like you want:

```
@Provider
public class ErrorExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final Throwable exception) {
        // this is an example of how to do something custom based on an annotation
        if(!resourceInfo.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(SomeCustomAnnotation.class) && !resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().isAnnotationPresent(SomeCustomAnnotation.class))
            return null; // do some custom thing here based on your annotation, maybe call another ExceptionMapper not annotated with @Provider ?
        return Response.status(500).entity("ERROR").build();
    }
}
```

It works for my purposes anyway.