# JAX-RS ExceptionMapper exceptions splitting

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS based web application. The application includes 2 types of APIs:

1. typical rest(json) enpoints
2. endpoint, which duplicates rest, but receives requests in XML format.

Both API produces different format response.

1. json
2. XML

I currently have single ExceptionMapper, to catch exceptions like:EJBAccessException, NotAllowedException...

Which can be produced by both API types.

My question: which is the best way to separate exception handling?
(reaction to same exception for rest api should generate JSON response, for XML - xml response)

Comment: Why do you have to duplicate resources just to support different content types?

Comment: By requirements.

Comment: you shouldn't have to split the responses if the messages are identical, you can pack them in the same object on output.   eg ErrorMessageForBothJSONXML   and have a field which is used to serialize out.  Generally, I like to have two exceptions which are thrown in this case, and inherit from the single exception, which is caught by the ExceptionMapper

Comment: Thanks for response. My case have a lot of legacy, Paul, your solution is not easy to integrate. But I have found solution by my self. And here you can see something similar what I already have done - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375502/jersey-register-exceptionmapper-for-resource-methods

Answer (score 0):

```
@Context private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

@Override
public Response toResponse(Throwable throwable) {
    if(resourceInfo.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(RestExceptionMapper.class)) {
        return RestExceptionHandler.handle(throwable, servletRequest);
    } else if (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(SoapExceptionMapper.class)) {
        SoapExceptionHandler.handle(throwable, servletRequest);
    }
    return Response.status(500).entity("ERROR").build();
}
```

This is a template of my new exception mapper. Linkage to resource using annotation.